# flask type error, list object not callable

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm passing a data Array to flask function using Ajax post request in Jquery. However the flask request.form.getlist not able to get this list and shows Type error: list object not callable

My code:

```
@app.route('/DeleteRow', methods=['POST'])
def signUpUser():
    if request.method == "POST":
        clicked=request.form.getlist('id[]')
    print(clicked[0])
```

ids is the Array which is sent to the Ajax post request:

```
var ids = new Array();
  for(i=0;i<table.rows('.selected').data().length;i++)
  {
      ids[i]=table.rows('.selected').data()[i][3];
  }


  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {id:ids},
   url: "DeleteRow",
   success: function(data){
     alert('Do you want to delete this row: ' + data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP POST requests made via AJAX have a Content-Type header of `application/json` and are thus collected in `request.json`.

HTTP Requests made with a Content-Type header of `multipart/form-data` are those that get collected in `request.form`.

Use:

```
clicked = request.json.get('id')
```